# How can I show file in sdcard to user?

Tags: android

I want to show user my apk file using intents, here is the code:

```
 SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File(SDCardRoot,fileName);
 if (file.exists()) {

Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new    
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,path);                                
startActivity(intent);
```

but it is giving me ActivityNotFoundException,I want to start the apk file so that user can install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new    
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,path);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");                    
startActivity(intent);
```